# laws of logic / rules of logic? to what extent is the distinction pertinent?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Laws of logic are propositions, and more precisely, propositions that are always true ( true in all interpretations).

For example : [ (A OR B) & ~B ] --> A

Rules of logic are " commands" , " imperatives" ; as such  they are not propositions ( declarative sentenses)  for they are neither true nor false; for example :

" from (A OR B) and ~B , infer A".

Is this account correct?

For example, is it helpful to distinguish the "law of modus ponens" and the "modus ponens rule"?

Are there logical languages / systems for which this distinction does not hold?

Comment: (-1) should I understand that the distinction is obviously pertinent or that it obviously isn't?

Comment: Do you have a source for the definitions of law vs. rule you give here? To the best of my knowledge those aren't technical terms (and I suspect that's what the downvote is about). That said, the distinction you're pointing at is indeed an important one (and I've upvoted).

Comment: I think I encountered this distinction in Robert Blanché's Introduction to contemporary logic ( Introduction à la logique contemporaine): " The first way [to conceive of logic] is to consider it as a deontology of reasoning. Laws [here] have a lower status than rules  , and often are not well distinguished from rules. (...) Such a logic is not properly a science, for rules are, as such, neither true nor false. (...) Logic [ thus understood ] will be classified amongst "normative sciences",...

Comment: .... in the same way as ethics or esthetics. This conception could be considered as old-fashioned: [however] it is newly in favour with recent systems of natural deduction". ( Chapter 1, §3) - Blanché establishes a link between the law/rules distinction and the traditional disputed question " is logic a science or an art?"

Comment: For FOL, we may equate "laws of logic" with [logical truth (i.e. *valid* formulas)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667377/when-and-where-the-concept-of-valid-logic-formula-was-defined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, neither "law of logic" nor "rule of logic" has a specific technical meaning - at least in the context of mathematical logic (I don't know about the philosophy side of things). That said, the difference between (in a given system) *axioms, theorems, and tautologies* on the one hand and *inference rules* on the other is extremely important in proof theory; see e.g. [this Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132268/deduction-theorem).

Logic is broad enough that there isn't a single "most general" situation, but the following is a pretty good summary of a wide range of cases:

- We have a set $S$ of things called *sentences*, and a *deduction relation* $\vdash$ on $S$. That is, $\vdash$ is a subset of $\mathcal{P}(S)\times S$, with "$(X,y)\in$ $\vdash$" being interpreted as "from $X$, infer $y$," and abbreviated by "$X\vdash y$." *(Usually $S$ is more than just a set, and in particular $S$ is often a free algebra over some signature whose elements are our logical connectives.)*
- The *tautologies* of the deductive system $(S,\vdash)$ are the sentences $y$ such that $\emptyset\vdash y$. For a given set $\Gamma\subseteq S$, the *theorems* of $\Gamma$ are the sentences $y$ such that $\Gamma\vdash y$, and when focusing on a single such $\Gamma$ we call elements of $\Gamma$ *axioms*.
- An *inference rule* is a pair $(\Gamma,y)$ with $\Gamma\subseteq S$ and $y\in S$ (or a set of such pairs closed under appropriate substitutions). Generally $\vdash$ is "generated by" a collection of inference rules in the obvious way, and we can talk about a given inference rule being [*admissible*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_rule) (with respect to $\vdash$).

The relevant topic is **algebraic logic**, and I strongly recommend [this paper of Blok and Pigozzi](https://orion.math.iastate.edu/dpigozzi/papers/aaldedth.pdf) as a good introduction.